# If $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$ and $\beta>0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{\alpha} \int_0^{\frac1{n^\beta}}f(x)=0$ for all $\alpha<\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I'm thinking of splitting the limit into two parts, one with the $n^\alpha$ and the other with the integral. If $\alpha<0$, then $\lim n^{\alpha}=0$. But I can't figure out how to prove the limit of the integral is 0. (It clearly is, because $\frac{1}{n^\beta}\to0$ which means the area under $f(x)$ must also go to 0.) I'm just not sure which method to use to prove it.

Comment: Do you mean $f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: Yes, that what I mean.

Comment: When $f$ is Riemann integrable, it is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t=n^\beta x$ and since $f$ is continuous on the compact $[0,1]$ then $f$ is bounded by $M>0$ then
$$ n^{\alpha} \left|\int_0^{\frac1{n^\beta}}f(x)dx\right|=n^{\alpha-\beta}\left|\int_0^1f(tn^{-\beta})dt\right|\leq n^{\alpha-\beta}\int_0^1|f(tn^{-\beta})|dt\leq Mn^{\alpha-\beta}\to 0 $$
so you can conclude.